# Select first row in each GROUP BY group in mySQL and Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

As the title suggests, I'd like to select the first row of each set of rows grouped with a GROUP BY.

Specifically, if I've got a `user_analytics` table that looks like this:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, country_name, code, COUNT(*) as total_visitors FROM referral_analytics
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2020-01-03'AND '2021-01-03'
GROUP BY code,country_name,latitude,longitude
```

**My Output:**

```
latitude  | longitude  | country_name              | code| total_visitors
----------+------------+---------------------------+-----+---------------
32.548328 | -92.045235  | United States of America | US  | 1
33.389011 | -111.844017 | United States of America | US  | 1
34.060734 | -118.239738 | United States of America | US  | 1
38.935699 | -77.3508    | United States of America | US  | 1
39.613087 | -104.883926 | United States of America | US  | 1
39.751099 | -104.997101 | United States of America | US  | 1
39.772247 | -86.156517  | United States of America | US  | 1
39.966381 | -83.012772  | United States of America | US  | 4
```

I'd like to query the first or min latitude and longitude for each group in MySQL/ Laravel query.
Something like this:

**Expected Output:**

```
latitude  | longitude  | country_name              | code| total_visitors
----------+------------+---------------------------+-----+---------------
32.548328 | -92.045235  | United States of America | US  | 11
```

Comment: This is a query, not a table.

Comment: Note that grouping by the float latitude and longitude values might not work as you expect, as these values are not _exact_.

Comment: may I get only the first value of each group?

Comment: Are you saying you want to group by just country name and get total visitors as well as an arbitrary row belonging to that group? In that case then take a look at something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql

Comment: Did you managed to find an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Got this -

```
SELECT MIN(user_latitude) as latitude, MIN(user_longitude) as longitude, user_country_name, user_country_code, COUNT(*) as total_visitors
        FROM referral_analytics
        WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2020-01-03'AND '2021-01-03'
        GROUP BY user_country_code,user_country_name
```

Comment: Selecting a coordinate closest to 0,0 seems like an odd objective

Comment: Note this will select the smallest latitude and longitude but will not select the smallest pair of lon-lat so if you had one entry with `0, 10` and another entry with `10, 0` this would end up selecting `0,0` which are not coordinates that exist on your database together